# Rolling Time Series AR(1) Regression Estimation in Python dataframe and MovingOLS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

2 questions here:

First. I have a dataframe like this:

```
           Date       Y           X1          X2          X3
22   2004-05-12  9.348158e-09  0.000081  0.000028     0.000036   
23   2004-05-13  9.285989e-09  0.000073  0.000081     0.000097   
24   2004-05-14  9.732308e-09  0.000085  0.000073     0.000096   
25   2004-05-17  2.235977e-08  0.000089  0.000085     0.000099   
26   2004-05-18  2.792661e-09  0.000034  0.000089     0.000150   
27   2004-05-19  9.745323e-09  0.000048      
1000   2004-05-20  1.835462e-09  0.000034  0.000048     0.000099   
1001   2004-05-21  3.529089e-09  0.000037  0.000034     0.000043   
1002   2004-05-24  3.453047e-09  0.000043  0.000037     0.000059   
1003   2004-05-25  2.963131e-09  0.000038  0.000043     0.000059   
1004   2004-05-26  1.390032e-09  0.000029  0.000038     0.000054
```

I want to run a rolling 100-day window OLS regression estimation, which is:

First for the 101st row, I run a AR(1) regression of Y using the 1st to 100th rows, and estimate Y for the 101st row;

Then for the 102nd row, I run a AR(1) regression of Y using the 2nd to 101st rows, and estimate Y for the 102nd row;

Then for the 103rd row, I run a AR(1) regression of Y using the 2nd to 101st rows, and estimate Y for the 103rd row;

......

Until the last row.

I'm now using the following code for an AR(1) regression:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data_in['Y'],'Date':data_in['Date']})
df = df.set_index('Date')
ar = statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR(df)
res_ar = ar.fit(maxlag=1)
```

Of course it's free to use any possible method to achieve the goal. How to do this？

Second. When I use MovingOLS, the output is like this:

```
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <RV(t-1)> + <RV(t-1)*RQ(t-1)^0.5> + <RV(t-1|t-5)> + <RV(t-1|t-22)>
             + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         1420
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   5

R-squared:         0.3370
Adj R-squared:     0.3352

Rmse:              0.0001

F-stat (4, 1415):   179.8353, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 4, resid 1415

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RV(t-1)     0.5031     0.0496      10.14     0.0000     0.4058     0.6003
RV(t-1)*RQ(t-1)^0.5   -55.2344    10.1137      -5.46     0.0000   -75.0573   -35.4115
RV(t-1|t-5)     0.1736     0.0542       3.20     0.0014     0.0673     0.2799
RV(t-1|t-22)     0.2381     0.0563       4.23     0.0000     0.1276     0.3485
intercept     0.0000     0.0000       2.22     0.0268     0.0000     0.0000
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

How does it integrate many regression results into such a summary？

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to model your samples with an equation. This equation has many parameters (called estimators). The value of the estimator will change depending on the training data that is used to calculate it. When you are estimating such model parameters using cross-validation on your data this means that you will get a distribution for each of these parameters. Basically `Coef` will be the average of the estimator and `Std Err` will be its standard deviation. The other numbers tell you about the confidence that these statistics about your estimators are correct.

Answer (score 0):

MovingOLS is not particularly efficient, so for large data sets where there is only a single X variable in each regression model, it makes sense to have a custom implementation as the speed differential can be substantial.  Such an example would be something like this:

```
def rolling_regression(df, x_name, y_name, window):
    window_inv = 1.0 / window
    df['X_SUM'] = df[x_name].rolling(window, min_periods=window).sum()
    df['Y_SUM'] = df[y_name].rolling(window, min_periods=window).sum()
    df['XY_SUM'] = (df[x_name] * df[y_name]).rolling(window, min_periods=window).sum()
    df['XX_SUM'] = numpy.square(df[x_name]).rolling(window, min_periods=window).sum()
    df['XY_COV'] = df['XY_SUM'] - window_inv * df['X_SUM'] * df['Y_SUM']
    df['X_VAR'] = df['XX_SUM'] - window_inv * numpy.square(df['X_SUM'])
    df['BETA'] = df['XY_COV'] / df['X_VAR']
    return df[['BETA']][window - 1:]
```

To use this function with an existing time series to compute an AR(1) model, you'd simply shift the time series in a separate column.

```
df[x_name] = df[y_name].shift(-1)
```

Regarding your second question, the results summary does not summarize the the full rolling regression, merely the last available window in the dataframe itself.